# How do I add a Name Prefix to a Contact using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts

Apple's Contacts App had a defined field for a name **prefix** (e.g. "Dr.").

Using AppleScript if I retrieve the `name` property, the prefix is included. However, there does not appear to be/exist a `prefix` property.  There **IS** a `suffix` property which I am able to read and write, but I need to be able to specifically WRITE (e.g. add) a prefix to a contact.

Any/All help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **AppleScript** *dictionary* (**⇧⌘L** ) for **Contacts**, look at the *properties* of the *class* **Person**.

If you have added a **Prefix** to the *contact* via, e.g., **Contacts** > **Card** > **Add Field**, then it is assigned to the `title` *property*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescritp
tell application "Contacts"
    set theContact to the first person ¬
        whose title is not missing value
    return title of theContact
end tell
```

Comment: Thank You‼️. Silly me thinking that a field labeled "Prefix" would be called prefix in AppleScript. LOL

Comment: May I ask … How did you get color to show up in your AppleScript sample???

Comment: @HirsuteJim, RE: "How did you get color to show up in your AppleScript sample?" --  Have a look at [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) -- I use, e.g., `<!-- language: lang-applescript -->` because when I write code, before posting it I have a _script_ that adds it and indents all the _code_ another _tab_ so it's ready to copy and paste into an answer.

Comment: Would you mind sharing said script to indent, tab, prep, etc??

Comment: @HirsuteJim , RE: "Would you mind sharing said script to indent, tab, prep, etc??" --  Here you go: https://paste.ee/p/Eustg  -- ( It deletes after 1H.)

Answer (score 1):

@HirsuteJim, here is **setting the prefix programatically**:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set title of person 1 to "Dr. "
    save
    quit -- optional
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks** to @user3439894 I ended up with:

```applescript
    tell application "Contacts"  
        tell every person in group "ALG"  
            set title to "(ALG)"  
            delete suffix  
            save  
        end tell  
    end tell
```